JsonProperty causes conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions on additional method
When I use JsonProperty, it causes the issue
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions (implicit name 'ndc'): found multiple explicit names: [ndc, isNdc], but also implicit accessor: [method com.himshers.supplychain.inventoryapi.model.LotItem#getNdc()][visible=true,ignore=false,explicitName=false]

My data class is the following and I want to have isNdc field on serialization as well.
data class LotItem(
    @JsonProperty("lotId") val lotId: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("ndc") val ndc: String? = null,
) {

    @JsonProperty("isNdc")
    fun isNdc(): Boolean {
        return ndc != null
    }
}

This is currently on Kotlin: 2.0.0, Jackson: 2.17.1, Java 21.
This used to work on Kotlin: 1.9.20, Jackson: 2.16.0, Java: 13.

If it used to work with kotlin 1.9 but broke in 2.0 I recommend filing an issue on Jacksons github.

I've just executed the java version of your code with Java 13 and Jackson 2.16.0 and the issue still persists. It doesn't seem like a problem of a newer Java or Jackson version. If it was, it should show up also without Kotlin. The exception you're experiencing seems like a regular Jackson's behavior, regardless of its version, where it is allowed only one type of getter (getNdc or isNdc) per property at the time.

Adding jackson-module-kotlin dependency solved the issue
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

